# Load a page fragment into a Twitter bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to load a page fragment using Twitter bootstrap's modal components? I want to load a page into the modal, but I only want a section of it. For example, I want the form on the page without the wrapping navigation. I've done this type of thing before using jquery tools overlays and jquery's .load function. But the modal stuff doesn't allow for this type of information to be passed in.

Here is some example text I'm working with:

```
 <a tabindex="-1"
    href="metadata.html"
    id="metadata-link"
    data-target="#modal"
    data-toggle="modal">Metadata</a>

 <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display:none;">
   <div class="modal-header">header<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a></div>
   <div class="modal-body"></div>
   <div class="model-footer">footer</div>
 </div>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#metadata-link').modal({show:false});
   });
 </script>
```

The 'metadata.html' page is a full html document. The contents of this page get loaded into the '.modal-body' element as expected. But the nothing displays...

If I switch the 'metadata.html' page for a page that contains only a 'div' contents, the modal displays.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bootstrap uses the jquery load method which allows a URL and a fragment selector to be specified:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

So in my case (adding a musician) i could use a normal link tag like this:

```
<a href="/musicians/new?editMode  .container form" class="btn pull-right newItem" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newItemModal" ><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Add</a>
```

Which extracts the form element from the container div and shows it in the newItemModal modal. This approach allows me to re-use the modal for other items

Comment: Do you know if this degrades well? In other words, does the user have the ability to click the link and be taken to the destination in the event that this part of the javascript does not load properly?

Comment: Yes, it can, but it depends on the specific values and how your server understands url's. If i do 'open link in new window' my browser uses that complete href as the path. So there will appear (to my server) to be a single query string parameter 'editMode .container form'. If the server knows to truncate at the space after editMode then all is fine. But if there is no question mark then the entire string will be treated as a url by the server, which generally wont work

Comment: Can be solved like this: `<a href="/musicians/new?editMode" onclick="this.href=this.href+' .container form'">`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it manually:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#metadata-link').click(function(){
       $.ajax(
       {
          url:'url-to-load-page',
          success: function(response){
            //do what ever you want here to extract the part you want
            $('#modal-div-content').html(adapted-response);
            $('#modal').modal('show');
          }
       });
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Declaring the fragment id using data-remote worked for me:**

```
<a href="remote.html" data-remote="remote.html #fragment" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
```